# how to check if element of list contains one of the elements of another list

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings
`['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv']`
and I need to return a list containing the elements of this list which contain any of the strings in `['a', 'g', 'y']`. I have attempted this with the following list comprehension

```
lst = ['asdf', 'qwer', 'zxcv']
target_strings = ['a', 'g', 'y']
[element for element in lst if any(target_strings) in element]
```

Which does not work, as `any(target_strings)` is a `bool`, not `string`. The target output in this case would be `['asdf']`.

Comment: use a nested loop

Answer (score 4):

The argument to `any()` should be a sequence of conditions. It returns true if any of the conditions is true.

You're giving it a sequence of strings. When a string is used as a condition, it's true if it's not empty. So you're just testing whether any of `target_strings` are not empty, which is always true.

Put the `in` test inside the `any()` argument.

```
[element for element in lst if any(s in element for s in target_strings)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You were close.

```
>>> [e for e in lst if any(t in e for t in target_strings)]
['asdf']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *@Barmar*'s and *@Tim Roberts*'s answers, to give an alternative approach, you can use set operations by making an [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) between the list of elements and the targets :

```
[e for e in lst if set(e).intersection(target_strings)] # which gives ['asdf']
```